# Hbase Fuzzy Row Filter returns zero rows

Tags: scala, hbase

I've a table with row key values as 100,200,300 where 00 is the fixed part and the 1st digit is variable.
I created a fuzzy filter with below code.
It returns no result.

I checked for the jars too.
I don't think there is any discrepancy in my hbase version and the hbase-client,hbase-server,hbase-common jars. They all are versioned hbase 1.1.2
I don't get any error too.
Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong.

Code :

```
var partialKey = "00"
var rowKey = "?"+partialKey
var rowKeyId = Bytes.toBytesBinary(rowKey)
val table = "PH_TEST_FUZZY"
val hbase_master = "xx.xxx.xx.xx:16000"
val zookeeper_master = "xx.xxx.xx.xx:2181,xx.xxx.xx.xx:2181,xx.xxx.xx.xx:2181"
val connection: Connection = getHbaseConfig(hbase_master, zookeeper_master)
val jobConfig: JobConf = new JobConf(connection.getConfiguration, this.getClass)
jobConfig.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, table)
val tableStatus: Table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(table))
val scan = new Scan
val fuzzyRowFilter = new org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Pair(rowKeyId,Array[Byte](1, 0, 0))
val rowKeyFilter = new FuzzyRowFilter(List(fuzzyRowFilter).asJava)
scan.setFilter(rowKeyFilter)
val scanner = tableStatus.getScanner(scan)
scanner.asScala.foreach(x=>println(Bytes.toString(x.getRow)))
```

Comment: Can you print any line without setFilter?

Comment: Yes, if I don't apply any filter. I get all the rowkeys what are present in my table.